# How to change the text of a text object in Crystal Reports? with Crystal Syntax

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to change the text of a text object using crystal reports syntax, this is what I have:

```
If ( {?@CodCta} like "2*" ) Then

( 

 ) 


If ( {?@CodCta} like "4*" ) Then
```

But I don't know how to capture the text object and change the text it has. This is my text object:

[image: format]

I am newb to Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1):

Text objects are static (no way to use a Crystal expression to change the text).
You can use a formula instead of a text objects to make the content dynamic.

Or, if you truly need to change the text in text objects, you can use 3rd-party tools that can do a mass update to Crystal Reports text objects. Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party Report Management Utilities [here](https://www.kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#doc).

Comment: oooh i didn't know that, anyway i started to make the formula that can print the message i want. Thanks anyway